# Garbage Collector and objects/variables created inside a method

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

When I create an object/variable inside a method, after the method calls, all the objects will be set to be collected by GC and all "primitive" variables (int, string, decimal...) are destroyed, right?

So, if yes:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    // Imagine an class that connects with ftp server
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    o.Connect(); 
}
```

If i have an error in the line `o.Connect()` and I have a `try``catch`only to log the error,`MyObject o` will be collected by GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set time when the garbage collector does its "collecting." There are three "generations" of objects and objects are promoted up a generation if they survive collection. So yes, if you "catch" the error in a try/catch block then the garbage collector will free up the memory taken up by your object.

You can find out more about garbage collection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.90))

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.90) There's supposed to be a closing parenthesis at the end but stack overflow isn't recognizing that as part of the link. Sorry!

Comment: Also, to add to the discussions in the other answers, you will need to close any unmanaged connections you have opened manually as the garbage collector does not take care of those. So it you have an open file handle, you will need to close it in your catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The GC will collect an object some time after the object is no longer reachable from any objects in scope. It may not collect it promptly, so if you want the connection to be ended promptly, you should use the `IDisposable` pattern and a `using` block.

(Note: The CLR GC behavior is not simple, and it provides few guarantees as to when an object will be collected. The general rule of thumb is to rely on the GC to reclaim memory, but take care of other resources, such as connections, explicitly.)

Comment: But if the connection has not succeeded? What will happens with the object when raises an erro in the line `o.Connect()`?

Comment: That's up to the internals of the object. The GC will *eventually* collect the object, and call the object's finalizer, but it's up to the object to make sure that its finalizer frees non-memory resources.

If all you're interested in is what happens to the memory, then it looks like `o` will be made available for collection after the method terminates, but to be certain, you need to know if the object might give anything else a reference to it during the constructor or `Connect`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the code line-by-line

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    MyObject o = new MyObject(); // local object
    o.Connect();
} // object o now goes out of scope and becomes subject for GC
```

But I guess the nature of your question is in *if you still be able to log an error*. And the answer is **yes**. There are two possible scenarios:

- `o.Connect` is *synchronous*, which means you will not hit the last `}` line before all the logic is executed
- `o.Connect` is *asynchronous*, let me call it `o.ConnectAsync`, which means you will hit the last `}` straightaway w/o waiting for the connection to do its magic. How is this possible? This is possible because `o.ConnectAsync` will (likely) be executed in a separate thread. The working thread of `o.ConnectAsync` will keep a reference to the `o` object and thus it will not become subject for GC. Only after async method is finished `o` will become available for GC.

Comment: But if the connection has not succeeded? What will happens with the object when raises an erro in the line `o.Connect()`? The object `o` will keeps in memory to the "eternity"?

Comment: `o` will become subject to GC, when no other object reference it. When you throw an exception, you (better) keep a stacktrace to the object. Thus it will be referenced to the point where you finish handling an exception. But after that, noone will be pointing to `o` and it will automatically become subject to GC. GC may not run for a while if there is no memory preasure.